# NSIS: How ExecWait handles exe's that otherwise crash

Tags: c++, windows, nsis

I have an exe that needs `VC++` environment to run and otherwise crashes.

If I run it in non VC++ environment, from command line or from C++ code [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) function, it obviously gets crashed and system error message is shown like below

[image]

But when I am executing it from `ExecWait` in NSIS script, its just executing it. The exe must still be crashing but its not showing any error messages.

If I'm right `ExecWait` as well uses `CreateProcess` function internally. Then why this difference?

Is there any flag in `CreateProcess` Function that needs to be passed to get this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSIS does not pass any special flags:

```
StartUp.cb=sizeof(StartUp);
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &StartUp, &ProcInfo)) ...
```

but before it gets to this point it does `SetErrorMode(SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX | SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);` which might affect things.

The other thing to remember is that a `SetOutPath` instruction in a NSIS script also changes the process working directory so if you set it to a path where those dll's exist the child process should pick them up as well...

Comment: Added `SetErrorMode(SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX | SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);` and got the same behavior. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 0):

Flawed assumptions.

The application does not crash. It fails to start.

It doesn't need to run in VC++, it merely needs to have available a standard DLL. NSIS probably needs the same DLL, and *does* ship with that DLL.

Comment: How NSIS knows not to start an exe  if the dll it needs is not present?

Comment: @foobar: NSIS doesn't know. Windows will complain.

Comment: In my case, it doesn't.

Comment: @foobar: Well, there's a screenshot in your post disagreeing with you.

Comment: That, as I mentioned, is in the case of using C++ or command prompt. Using NSIS, no error message comes.

Comment: @MSalters: NSIS runs on every Windows version since Win95 and does not depend on any CRT dll.